# Android's BitmapFactory returns corrupted image

Tags: java, android, bitmapfactory

I am participating in a project where we build an app which solves Rubiks' cubes. Initially we started with a desktop app using JavaFX but we decided to switch over to an Android app.

Since I already implemented a working model at least for color recognition, I wanted to reuse that and just build another UI around it. That is where I am stuck right now because I cannot even get Android's bitmap API to work. Unfortunately it looks like I need to stick with it since Swing/AWT/JavaFX image libraries are not available.

So I implemented a JUnit test which I cleaned up a bit:

```
package de.uniks.rubiksapp;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestBitmap {

    @Test
    public void testBitmap() {

        Resources resources = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources();

        InputStream testImageStream = resources.openRawResource(R.drawable.test_front);

        Bitmap testImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(testImageStream);

        //Bitmap testImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test_front);

        // --- Pixel readout would be here --- //

        System.out.println(testImageBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + testImageBitmap.getHeight() + "px");

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("test.png");
            testImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem currently is that the bitmaps I get from `BitmapFactory` seem to be corrupted. When I am trying to read specific pixels using `Bitmap.getPixel()`, they are always black. So I tried saving the image back to disk which works but the resulting files are only around 40 bytes large and cannot be opened.

Initially, I tried using `Bitmap.decodeResource()` instead of `Bitmap.decodeStream()` but that always returns images with a size of 100x100px, although my source images are 1240x800px large. Even when I use `Bitmap.Options` and set `inScaled = false`. At least the size is correct when using `Bitmap.decodeStream()`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you think that a bitmap is corrupted then display it on an ImageView so you can see it.

Comment: `out = new FileOutputStream("test.png");`. I wonder were that file would land? Where did you find it so you could try to open it? You should use a full pah there instead of only a file name as you do now.

Comment: `out = new FileOutputStream("test.png");` saves the image to the project root.

However, when I use `Bitmap.decodeResource()` in the main activity and set an ImageView to it like you suggested, it reads and displays the image correctly.

Any idea how to make it work in the Unit test as well?

Comment: `saves the image to the project root.`. What do you consder to be the projects root? Full path please.

Comment: The root directory where my project lives in. The unit test runs on my machine, not on a phone or an emulator. Saving to a full path does not make sense since it breaks the test on other peoples' machines. Also the file is being created and I can find it. What I just found out is that it is actually saved as a text file containing `Bitmap compressed as PNG with quality 100`, not the image itself.